# Final variables cannot be assigned in an enclosing type

Tags: java, oauth

I 'm trying to create an OAuth application, but I have a problem. Is there any way I can convert from String to anything (in this case "Verifier", which my library forces to use, otherwise illegal characters can be send to the server).

This is the part of the code which matters:

```
final Verifier verifier = null;
final TextBox txtbxHello = new TextBox();
Button btnSubmit = new Button("Submit");
  btnSubmit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        verifier = txtbxHello.getValue();
    }
  });
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken,verifier);
```

And the error is:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Verifier.
```

**EDIT**

Anyway, I was able to fix the error (using the value of verifier). 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please understand that your issue has **nothing** to do with Eclipse. You've got non-compilable code pure and simple. As noted, you can't change a final variable as you're trying to do. Instead perhaps you want to make verifier a class field.

Comment: I've tried it and the error is:
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field verifierClass.verifier

Comment: This suggests that you need to study your tutorials and texts on how to create and use objects, a basic concept in Java programming. Your verifier variable needs to be a non-static or instance variable, and your code above should be called in a non-static or instance method. Again, read up on how to create and use instance (non-static) variables and methods as you will need to understand this before you can move forward with Java.

Answer (score 3):

You can only assign final variables at declaration or in constructor. That's the meaning of the final keyword - the variable is read only.

Answer (score 1):

verifier is final variable and once you assign anything in it you can not assign another value in it so better to declare and assign value in once

Comment: I changed the question, please update your answer.
Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you have set variable "verifier" and "txtBxHello" as final (can be assigned to only once) so you cant reassign them.

that's what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Thanks!
Can you please update your answer, I changed the question.

Comment: the problem now is that you are trying to set a variable type of "Verifier" to a type of "String" (as thats what getValue() returns)

Answer (score 0):

Like above final cannot be assigned twice.

To solve it you may

- Declare the variable "verifier" as instance variable (in a class but not in any method), therefore it can be accessed in the anonymous class without being final, or
- Declare the variable "verifier" as a field in an object and set the value via a setter. Therefore you avoid assigning the final variable twice.

  ```
  final MyVerifier verifier = new MyVerifier();
  ...
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      verifier.setValue(txtbxHello.getValue());
  }
  ```

Comment: Great, but the value of txtbxHello is a String, and I cannot convert it to Verifier (or MyVerifier in your example).

Comment: I don't know about Verifier, but it isn't topic of this thread I guess. You can refer to its JavaDoc about how to construct a Verifier with String or create a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

For you new question, no you cannot change the type of a variable unless to a subclass or one that implements the interface.

Why not just declare "verifier" as String?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a value to a final variable but the compiler must be sure you will not access the variable before it is assigned and you will not reassign it.
Your problem in this case is that you have code that will execute in sequence and an event that will not. The onClick function will execute some time in the future.
Maybe you want this:

```
final TextBox txtbxHello = new TextBox();
Button btnSubmit = new Button("Submit");
btnSubmit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        final Verifier verifier = txtbxHello.getValue();
        Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken,verifier);
    }
});
```

But on the other hand TextBox.getValue() returns a String and you try to assign it to a Verifier variable. I think you are misunderstanding the API of that library.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what your problem is: You've made your new verifier variable a "Verifier" variable (whatever the heck that is), and you're trying to assign a String returned from the getValue() method into this variable. So since only you have the code for the Verifier class, you need to check to see if you can somehow add String information to the variable. Does it have a setText(...) method? Would you be better off not using a Verifier variable but rather a String variable?